# Pycharm jupyter buttons grayed out

Tags: pycharm, jupyter

I'm using Pycharm Pro 2018.2, following the guide [Using IPython/Jupyter Notebook with PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-notebook-with-product.html). When I get down to the [Adding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-notebook-with-product.html#91095315) section, I click the cell with the import statement, and its cell becomes green, but the Jupyter buttons (move cell up, move cell down, insert cell) are grayed out.

In the margin of the tutorial, it says

> Press ⎋ key to enable the action

But I don't see any such key, or a button on the screen that looks like that, and I don't recognize that symbol.

Why are the jupyter buttons grayed out, and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This is an exercise in getting used to a user interface that's new to me, while following a tutorial that has numerous missing or incorrect parts.

The box turns green when you click inside the text of an existing cell. In that mode, you cannot click the cell action buttons (they are grayed out). You can activate the buttons by clicking somewhere else in the cell, not in the text. For example, click on `ln[...]`. This makes the cell boundary turn black, and the buttons become active.